# Dropdown of tables to show content

Tags: php, mysql

This script allows the user to choose a table from the dropdown and then displays the contents of the chosen table.

1. At the moment the DB connection is working.
2. A list of tables is shown in the dropdown.

**Problem:** No content from the database table is shown.
I have checked through the code and everything looks OK, but it still only seems to partially work.

```
<?php 
//update this to your DB connection details.
$dbh = "localhost";
$dbn = "dbname";
$dbu = "dbuser";
$dbp = "dbpass";

$conn = mysql_connect($dbh,$dbu,$dbp) or die("Unable to connect do database.");
mysql_select_db($dbn, $conn) or die("Unable to select database.");

//Some vars for Order by and Limit.
if (!isset($ordBy)){
    $ordBy = 1;
}
if (!isset($ps)){
    $ps = 0;
}
if (!isset($ord)){
    $ord = 1;
}
if ($ord == 1){
    $tOrder = "ASC";
} else {
    $tOrder = "DESC";
}

//Tables drop-down

$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM $dbn") or die("Cannot list table names.");
echo "
<form name=\"table_browser\" action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\" method=\"GET\" >
    <select name=\"t\" onChange=\"javascript:submit();\">
        <option>Select a table</option>
";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    echo "        <option value=".$row[0].">".$row[0]."</option>\n";
}
echo "    </select>
</form>\n";

if (!isset($t)){
    die("Please select a table");
}

//Get number of rows in $t and then select
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $t") or die("The requested table doesn't exist.");
$total = mysql_result($result,0);
$qry = "SELECT * FROM $t ORDER BY ".$ordBy." ".$tOrder." LIMIT ".($ps*20).",20 ";

if (isset($qry)) {
    $result = mysql_query($qry) or die("The requested table doesn't exist.");
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < mysql_num_fields($result)) {
        $meta = mysql_fetch_field($result);
        if (!$meta) {
            echo "No information available on the table<br />\n";
        }
        $name[$i] = $meta->name;
        $i++;
    }
    //Display table details
    echo "Rows ".($ps*20+1)." to ".((($ps+1)*20 < $total) ? (($ps+1)*20) : ($total))." of $total from table: 

<b>$meta->table</b>\n<br /><br />\n";

    //Count results
    if ($ps > 0) {
        echo "<a href=\"browse.php?t=$t&ps=".($ps-1)."&ordBy=$ordBy&ord=$ord\">20 Previous</a> - ";
    } else {
        echo "20 Previous - ";
    }
    if ((($ps+1)*20) < $total ){
        echo "<a href=\"browse.php?t=$t&ps=".($ps+1)."&ordBy=$ordBy&ord=$ord\">Next 20</a>\n";
    } else {
        echo "Next 20\n";
    }

    //Column names
    echo "<br /><br />\n<table>\n    <tr>\n";
    for ($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++){
        echo "        <td><b><a href=\"browse.php?t=$t&ps=$ps&ordBy=$name[$j]&ord=".(-$ord)."\">$name[$j]</a></b>";
        if ($ordBy == $name[$j]) {

            echo "<img src=\"images/arrow$ord.gif\">";
        }
        echo "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "    </tr>\n";

    //Data
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "    <tr onmouseover=\"this.style.background='#DDDDDD'\" onmouseout=\"this.style.background=''\">";
        for ($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++){
            echo "<td>".$row[$name[$j]]."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>\n";
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, you need to elaborate.

Comment: Updates problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@gentlebreeze - my eyes hurt from trying to read that - but I can't see where you are actually setting the variable called $t - which is used to determine the table. You should have

```
$t = $_GET['t'];
```

somewhere before the line:

```
....if (!isset($t)){....
```

because you need to use it in the line:

```
....$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $t"....
```

and you should not be using mysql_query either - old and now deprecated. You should switch to PDO and bound variables.

Comment: great - happy to help. :))